# How to hide java console when running "firebase emulators:start"?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools, javaw

After I run the command `firebase emulators:start`, the java console pops up:
[image]

How can I run the firebase emulators without showing the console?
Is there a way to run the console in hidden mode?

Answer (score 0):

There's an open bug here, right now there's no flag provided by Firebase to avoid the popup:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3506

Comment: Maybe there is some possible workaround that doesn't require firebase?